# I get an unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++

Hello party people I've been getting this error from my compiler whenever i try to compile it This error has happened to many of my other codes have any ideas?

Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl viewaddressbook(void)" (?viewaddressbook@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl menu(void)" (?menu@@YAXXZ)

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl removeentry(void)" (?removeentry@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl menu(void)" (?menu@@YAXXZ)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
void menu();
void addentry();
void removeentry();
void viewaddressbook();

map<string, string>names;



int main()
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "1.View Address Book \n2. Add Entry \n3. Remove Entry" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        viewaddressbook();
        break;
    case 2:
        addentry();
        break;
    case 3:
        removeentry();
        break;
    }

}

void addentry()
{
    string email;
    string firstlast;
    cout << "Enter the persons email\n" << endl;
    cin >> email;
    cout << "Enter the person's first and last name";
    cin >> firstlast;
    names[email] = firstlast;
    cout << firstlast << " was added with the email of " << email << endl;

    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
}

void removeentry(map<string,string> names)
{
    string shrink;
    int choice;
    string nametoremove;
    if (names.empty())
    {
        cout << "You have no one to remove\n";
        menu();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Who do you want to remove ?" << endl;
        cin >> nametoremove;
        map<string, string>::iterator itr = names.find(nametoremove);
        if (itr == names.end())
        {
            cout << "Sorry no one by the name of" << nametoremove;
        }
        else if (itr != names.end())
        {
            cout << "You sure you want to remove " << nametoremove << "\n\n1.Yes\n2.No" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                names.erase(itr);
                cout << nametoremove << " was removed";
                menu();
                break;
            case 2:
                menu();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void viewaddressbook(map<string,string> names)
{
    for (map<string, string>::iterator itr = names.begin(); itr != names.end();)
    {
        cout << itr->first << "|" << itr->second;
    }
    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
    menu();
}
```

Comment: Because no such function exists in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your functions

```
void removeentry();
void viewaddressbook();
```

don't have *definitions*. Rather you *defined*

```
void removeentry(map<string,string> names)
void viewaddressbook(map<string,string> names)
```

so linker is not able to *resolve calls* for

```
removeentry();
viewaddressbook();
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the functions at the top of the file as:

```
void menu();
void addentry();
void removeentry();
void viewaddressbook();
```

but the definitions you use don't match:

```
void removeentry(map<string,string> names)
{
   // ...
}
void viewaddressbook(map<string,string> names)
{
   // ...
}
```

Change your declarations at the top to match the function definitions to fix the error messages:

```
void menu();
void addentry();
void removeentry(map<string,string> names);
void viewaddressbook(map<string,string> names);
```

Comment: He's also calling viewaddressbook() with no parameters.